# Como reproduzir áudio automaticamente na inicialização de um programa?

Tags: java, áudio

Pretendo que o áudio seja reproduzido assim q o software iniciar. 
Se tiverem alguma sugestão para posicionamento do botão de audio no frame principal,a vontade...

Segue código para análise:

Classe principal

```
package Interface;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ClasseFrame cf= new ClasseFrame();
        cf.setVisible(true);

        //Chama o método para reproduzir o audio
            new TocarSom();
        }               
    }
```

Classe para reproduzir o audio

```
package Interface;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TocarSom extends JFrame {

    JButton tocar = new JButton(new ImageIcon("/Imagens/Blue_Bird.jpg"));

    public TocarSom() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tocar.setBounds(480, 250, 250, 250);//(coluna,linha,comprimento,largura);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        add(tocar);
        tocar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                play("BlueBird");
            }
        });
    }

    public void play(String nomeDoAudio) {
        URL url= TocarSom.class.getResource(nomeDoAudio+".wav");
        AudioClip audio= Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual o problema do código?

Comment: Com o código nenhum, só não sei reproduzi-lo automaticamente

Comment: Já tentou colocar no construtor?

Comment: Essa classe "TocarSom" é só pra reproduzir o som ou tambem é uma tela?

Comment: Tentei colocar no construtor e n deu certo. 
A classe "TocarSom" é tela tbm, tem o JButton q reproduz o audio ao clicar;

Comment: Qual classe deveria tocar som ao iniciar afinal?

Comment: A classe Main .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
package Interface;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ClasseFrame cf= new ClasseFrame();
        cf.setVisible(true);

        //Chama o método para reproduzir o audio
            new TocarSom().play("nome do arquivo de audio");
        }               
    }
```

Comment: DEU CERTO!!! Muito obrigado cara!!!

Comment: @Nakury se a resposta ajudou a resolver o problema, você pode aceitá-la clicando no `v` para que a questão possa ser dada como já solucionada.